# BIRT Reporting Chart dataset mismatch

Tags: sql-server, charts, birt

I am using Birt Designer 4.4+, and BIRT 3.2.23 engine. I have my report attached to an SQLServer datasource, and have most of the report completed. I have a summary section of the report which looks something like the section below...

```
Date Range  | Category 1 | Category 2
--------------------------------------
At Start    | 203        | 19
At End      | 111        | 29
Open During | 23         | 04
```

I need to create a pie chart to show the % of category 1 versus the other category(s). My problem is that the BIRT pie charts only allow me to show data based on the left column (the date range) for a specific column (e.g. I could compare date ranges against category 1. It will not allow you to compare say - the values of category 1 against category 2 at end. For note, in this example I am only interested in comparisons at the end of the date range.

I'v decided to attempt to create a new datasource that only queries the values 'at end', however am left with an SQL select that looks similar to this..

```
Date Range   | Category 1  | Category 2
-----------------------------------------
At End       | 101         | 29
```

I'd like to swap this on the axis to look similar to this...

```
Date Range   | At End
-----------------------
Category 1   | 101
Category 2   | 29
```

I'v looked into pivots, but it does not seem like it will work in my specific case, since I have something similar to the query below. Any advice on this topic is appreciated. Also any workarounds in BIRT is also appreciated if I do not have to change my data set. It looked like it might be an option in later versions of BIRT but sadly I do not have the option of updating currently.

**Original Dataset**

```
SELECT 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN itc.category_id=1230 THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END
    ) AS cAtEnd,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN (itc.category_id=1233 OR itc.category_id=1234) THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END
    ) AS rAtEnd,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN (itc.category_id=1235 OR itc.category_id=1236) THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END
    ) AS aAtEnd
FROM 
    i 
JOIN 
    itc ON itc.i_id=i.id AND itc.category_id IN (1230, 1233, 1234, 1235, 1236)
```

I should note that I shortened the SQL considerably - so if it seems like something is missing it is likely because I cut it out (or changed the name for simplicity/etc). The basic idea though is still the same.

Aside - My question is very similar in nature to the question found here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/62398/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding an easier way to create the desired result - please note I would still be interested in any other solutions to this (perhaps shorter ones or ones that do not have as many possible issues).

Create a new Data Set, simply UNION ALL to create the desired rows. Since my dataset only involved 3 rows it was not too bad.

```
SELECT total, 'set one' FROM table
UNION ALL 
SELECT total2, 'set two' FROM table2
```

This will create the desired SQL result set, that can be used in a regular fashion on the BIRT report.

I really hope I did not over-complicate this for no reason.